# loop through a parameter of a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, parameters, parameter-passing

How to loop through one parameter of a function, to give the result with each new loop.

```
//This ray is a 2D array with fixed length
//ray.length = 2;

var ray = [[x_Origin,y_Origin],[x_Destination,y_Destination]];



//This polyline is a 2D array with changeable length
//polyline.length = n
//for simplifying, let n=8 here

var polyline = [[2,4],[8,2],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14],[22,43],[15,15]];

//This polyline is cutted into (n-1) segments, each segment is also a 2D array with a fixed length = 2

//the 2nd point of 1st segment is the 1st point of the 2nd segment and so on...

//it looks like this

var seg1 = [[2,4],[8,2]];
var seg2 = [[8,2],[11,11]];
//...
var seg7 = [[22,43],[15,15]];


//That is my function, it takes 2 parameters
intersectionRaySeg(ray, seg);


//ray is 2D array of length 2 as mentioned above

//seg is also 2D array of length 2 as mentioned above also
```

The function above returns the intersection coordinates of the ray and a segment if there is an intersection, else it returns "no intersection"

But I am stucking with the problem above, I would write a for-loop to give the result, each at newline after checking with all segments
and I would not write a list of variables seg1, seg2, ... and so on, then check each manually, that is not practical :(

e.g. console.log()
then I get for example:

```
//no intersection
//no intersection
//coordinates (my function returns them already)
//no intersection
//coordinates (my function returns them already)
//coordinates (my function returns them already)
```

Comment: Yes, to write a loop you have to put your values in a data structure like an array, not in multiple variables

Comment: Why split `polyline` into separate variables in the first place?  Just pass `polyline[0]`, `polyline[1]` etc if the function only needs one section of it.

Comment: @Bergi https://jsfiddle.net/18cdb0mp/

Comment: @Daniel Beck the parameter "seg" that the function takes, composed of two points let say AB, polyline[0] = A, polyline[1] = B, and so on...

Comment: ...yes?  We must be misunderstanding each other because that's exactly what I meant: instead of checking `seg1`, `seg2`, `seg3` etc, which as you point out would be impractical, just iterate over the array `polyline` and call `intersectionRaySeg` with each element `polyline` contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more simple way using `for()`:

```js
var polyline = [[2,4],[8,2],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14],[22,43],[15,15]];
var seg = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    seg[i] = [polyline[i], polyline[i+1]];
}

// print out
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    console.log(seg[i][0] + " | " + seg[i][1]);
}
```

Using some `map()`:

```js
var polyline = [[2,4],[8,2],[11,11],[12,12],[13,13],[14,14],[22,43],[15,15]];
// map() create a new array seg based on each elements in polyline.
var seg = polyline.map(function(item, index, polyline) {
   if (index != 7)
 return [polyline[index], polyline[index+1]];
});

// Different than for(), seg will have 8 element, so we need to remove the last element from seg array.
seg.splice(7, 1);

// print out
seg.map(function (item) {
    console.log(item[0]+" | "+item[1]);
});
```

Hope that it's what you want. Read more about .map() here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: could you please explain it to me, I'm still a beginner, how it works this. It displays 2,4, 8,2,    8,2, 11,11, etc...

Comment: The `.map()` method is something more advanced than a normal `for()` loop so you may need a little time to get used to it. Honestly I've just learned it some days ago.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me yeah, I will get used of map().